# Angular 14 - How can I trigger a function when my Service Variable changes?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have 2 components and a Service that I would like to link like so:

1. Component 1 triggers a function inside Service on click
2. Service then gets data from an API and stores it
3. Component 2 gets the data that has been stored and displays it

So far I managed to get steps 1 and 2 working but I can't get my Component 2 to get the updated value, I'm still new to Angular so I must have not grasped a basic concept I suppose, here's the code (I removed unnecessary parts like the form and so on)

Component 1

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";
    import axios from "axios";
    import {UserService} from "../../user.service";
    import {map, Observable, startWith} from "rxjs";
    import {CreatureType} from "../../models/creaturetype.model";
    import {Creature} from "../../models/creature.model";
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-creatures-form',
      templateUrl: './creatures-form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./creatures-form.component.scss']
    })
    export class CreaturesFormComponent implements OnInit {
    
    constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder , private UserService: UserService ) {}
      ngOnInit(): void {}
      onSubmitCustomCreature() {
        // @ts-ignore
        let creature : string = '/api/creatures/'+this.CreatureControl.value.id // "creature": "/api/creatures/1"
        let references = {
          capacities : [],
          gears : [],
          effects : [],
          turn : []
        }
        const customCreature = { ...this.customCreaturesForm.value, creature: creature , account: '/api/accounts/'+this.UserService.user.id , ...references }
    
        const headers = {
          "Content-Type" : 'application/json'
        }
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/custom_creatures' , customCreature, {headers}).then( (res) => {
          console.log(res)
    
          this.UserService.setCreatures(this.UserService.user.id)
        })
      }
    
    }
```

Component 2

```js
    import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import { UserService} from "../user.service";
    import { Observable , of } from "rxjs";
    import axios from "axios";
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-cards-panel',
      templateUrl: './cards-panel.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./cards-panel.component.scss']
    })
    export class CardsPanelComponent implements OnInit {
    
    
      panelActive : boolean = false
      cards$! : any
      creatures : any
    
    
      constructor(private UserService: UserService) {
    
    
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
    
          axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/accounts/1', {
            headers : {
              "Accept" : 'application/json'
            }
          }).then( (res) => {
            this.UserService.setUser(res.data)
            // this.getAccountCreatures()
          })
        
        this.UserService.getCreatures().subscribe(data => {
          this.cards$ = data
          console.log(this.cards$) // only trigger on Init, never updates
        })

    // also tried this but it never triggers aswell
    // this.cards$ = of(this.UserService.userCreatures).subscribe((data) => {
    //   console.log(data)
    // })


    
      }
  
    }
```

Service

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {User} from "./models/user.model";
    import {Observable, Subject} from "rxjs";
    import axios from "axios";
    import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class UserService {
    
      user!: User
      userCreatures: Subject<any> = new Subject()
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    
      setUser(user : User) {
        this.user = user
      }
    
      setCreatures(id: number) {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/custom_creatures?account=/api/accounts/'+id , {
          headers: {
            "Accept" : 'application/json'
          }
        }).then( (res) => {
          console.log(res)
          this.userCreatures = res.data
          console.log(this.userCreatures)
        })
    
    
        console.log(this.getCreatures())
      }
    
      getCreatures() {
        return this.userCreatures
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Some questions:
* What exactly do you mean by _storing_ the data that comes back from the API? Where do you want to store it? Local storage, application state ...

* Ideally, component 2 is included in the template of component 1. Because you can then pass the updated data (which was fetched after clicking on something) directly from component 1  to component 2 via an input variable. Is that the case here? Can you share how component 1 and 2 are related to each other?

Comment: …why axios and not the build-in http client? And why have a service and then still do http calls from your components?

Comment: @Karel component 2 is not a child of component 1, component 1 is a form used to create a new entity in my api database, Component 2 is the list which shows every creatures the user has created so they can' have a child-parent relation as they are not meant to be shown near one another.

When I say store the data I mean in the variable called userCreature from my Service which is just a get from my API that I trigger evertyime a new Creature has been posted by the user

Comment: @MikeOne I tried the HTTP CLient and got no results so I tried with Axios which I'm more familiar with just as a test

Comment: If these components don't live next to each other, you'll need some form of persistance which in your case will probably be the database. So it seems to me your service needs a `saveCreature` method (POST call) and a `getCreatures` method (GET call). `saveCreature` is called when your form is saved and creates a new record in the db. `getCreatures` is called every time component 2 is initialized.

Comment: @Karel But that would mean calling the API multiple times which I would like to prevent, the Component 2 is a tab that can be opened or closed, I don't want to call the API everytime the user opens the tab if there's a way to prevent that, what I want to achieve is a way for Component 2 to update when `SaveCreature` is called

Comment: In that case, the options I can immediately think of are [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) or implementing state management. In the former, the server will send a message to the client saying a new creature is created and hence, the component should update. In the latter, `saveCreature` will update the application state and the component view updates because it listens for state updates. Popular state management libraries for Angular are [ngxs](https://www.ngxs.io/) and [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/).

Comment: Reading your last comment again, state management probably won't be any good. If the application runs in multiple browsers tabs, that means there are multiple instances of the app and each instance has its own state. So if you run `saveCreature` in tab 1 and expect a component in tab 2 to update, then you'll need to inform the instance of tab 2 e.g. via a server-sent event. Also have a look at the [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API), which allows basic communication between tabs (though I doubt it will fit your use case).

Answer (score -1):

I'm gonna be honest, I'm a bit too lazy to figure out your entire use case. I prepared a simple example to let you see how to call an api in one component and read the result from another.

I'm just getting a dumb joke from the jokes api.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yhhegu?file=src/app/api.service.ts

**Service**

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ApiService {
  url = 'https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Programming?type=single';
  apiResult = 'no joke yet';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  callApi() {
    this.http
      .get(this.url)
      .subscribe((res: any) => (this.apiResult = res.joke));
  }
}
```

**Calling Component**

```js
export class CallComponent {
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  callApi() {
    this.apiService.callApi();
  }
}
```

```html
<button (click)="callApi()">CALL API</button>
```

**Reading Component**

```js
export class ReadComponent {
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  get apiResult(){
    return this.apiService.apiResult;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>{{ apiResult }}</p>
```

You don't need to create a wrapper method / getter method for the service, you can declare it as `public` and use it directly in your html. I prefer this way because the linting / auto complete / refactoring in html is not great.

Angular's change detection will know when `apiResult` has changed and your html will update automatically. Services are singleton so the service property will persist as long as your app does.

If you require that other components execute other functions on receiving the result, you can use a `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject` instead of a simple local variable in the service. Let me know if you need any more details.